# TypeScript extend discord.js with local declarations

Tags: typescript

I am trying to get the following to work:

```js
// src/types.ts
declare module 'discord.js' {
  interface Guild {
    ensureAvailability: () => Promise<GuildMember>;
  }
```

```js
// src/database/entities/GuildMember.ts
@Entity()
export class GuildMember extends BaseEntity {
  @PrimaryColumn()
  id: string;
```

The reason I am trying to prevent imports at the top of the types file is to be able to still use the types inside the file inside any other file in the src folder, is there a way I can still use GuildMember inside the promise without importing the class at the top?

Comment: `The reason I am trying to prevent imports at the top of the types file is to be able to still use the types inside the file inside any other file in the src folder` I don't get that part of the question. Just import the types in every file?

Comment: I would have to rewrite a lot if I turn the file into a module, I was looking for a solution to maybe import a file inside declare module

Comment: Okay, so you have previously written it in JavaScript?